# Unable to create " Table In A text" file with C# but working code working properly in console

Tags: c#, string, formatting, text-files

I was trying to store some  tabular formatted data in a text file. 
I have found some code to create table console
and I was able to generate table formatted data on console,
but I don't know why it's not working for text files.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace part1johnskeet
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\tabletxt.txt", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);


        Console.WriteLine("writing File");

        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine("----------------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("First Name | Last Name  |   Age");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Bill", "Gates", 51));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny", "Depp", 44));
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");










        sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");

        sw.WriteLine("Name".PadRight(13, ' ') + "Unit".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "Rate".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "Total".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("fas".PadRight(13, ' ') + "10".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "710".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "22.55".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("asd 1".PadRight(13, ' ') + "10.25".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "20.25".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "800.55".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("asd".PadRight(13, ' ') + "13.5".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "35".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "600.25".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine(" adas".PadRight(13, ' ') + "14.3".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "10".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "143".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("asdas".PadRight(13, ' ') + "10".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "22.5".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "220.5".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("asdas".PadRight(13, ' ') + "700".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "16.5".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "800.15".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");
        sw.WriteLine("sdfefsdfe34rs".PadRight(13, ' ') + "800".PadLeft(10, ' ') + "10".PadLeft(6, ' ') + "8000".PadRight(8, ' ') + "");

        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Edna", "Parker", 114));
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-10} | {2,5}", "Johnny", "Depp", 44));






        string string1 = "asdf";
        string string2 = "ffs";
        string string4 = "gahah";
        string string5 = "kjshdfkjh";
        string string6 = "fg";
        string string7 = "kkkdd";
        string string8 = "asdasdf";
        string string9 = "somelongtext";

        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("string1: {0,-10} string2: {1,-10}", string1 + ",", string2));
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("string4: {0,-10} string5: {1,-10}", string4 + ",", string5));
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("string6: {0,-10} string7: {1,-10}", string6 + ",", string7));
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("string8: {0,-10} string9: {1,-10}", string8 + ",", string9));





        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("string1: {0,-10} string2: {1,-10}", string1 + ",", string2));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("string4: {0,-10} string5: {1,-10}", string4 + ",", string5));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("string6: {0,-10} string7: {1,-10}", string6 + ",", string7));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("string8: {0,-10} string9: {1,-10}", string8 + ",", string9));





        // Create array of 5-tuples with population data for three U.S. cities, 1940-1950.
        Tuple<string, DateTime, int, DateTime, int>[] cities = 
      { 
          Tuple.Create("Los Angeles", new DateTime(1940, 1, 1), 1504277, 
                     new DateTime(1950, 1, 1), 1970358),
         Tuple.Create("New York", new DateTime(1940, 1, 1), 7454995, 
                     new DateTime(1950, 1, 1), 7891957),  
         Tuple.Create("Chicago", new DateTime(1940, 1, 1), 3396808, 
                     new DateTime(1950, 1, 1), 3620962),  
         Tuple.Create("Detroit", new DateTime(1940, 1, 1), 1623452, 
                     new DateTime(1950, 1, 1), 1849568) };

        // Display header 
        string header = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8}{2,12}{1,8}{2,12}{3,14}\n",
                                      "City", "Year", "Population", "Change (%)");
        Console.WriteLine(header);
        sw.WriteLine(header);
        string output;
        foreach (var city in cities)
        {
            output = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8:yyyy}{2,12:N0}{3,8:yyyy}{4,12:N0}         {5,14:P1}",
                                   city.Item1, city.Item2, city.Item3, city.Item4,                            city.Item5,
                                   (city.Item5 - city.Item3) / (double)city.Item3);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            sw.WriteLine(output);
        }


        sw.WriteLine("-------------------------------");

        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("File written");



    }



}
}
```

Here Is my code with different ways to create table in console

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. First thing I'd do is check your permissions for "D:\tabletxt.txt". Can you open that location in windows and add a new text file with Explorer?

Comment: Code works fine for me too but files being created are not have the format as console

Comment: You're using different formatting techniques in the console code and the text-file code. Try modifying your console code to use sw.writeline instead of console.writeline (and remove the duplicated lines, obviously). See if that's what you're looking for. Otherwise be more specific about your expectations for this code.